# Should I save images in database or in a folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to store some photos that I take from a web service to my phone for the case when I don't have internet connectivity. I am storing data to a database but i have a question: should I store in the database the URL of the photo and the photo in a folder, or store the image in the database? The volume of photos shouldn't be great; something like 200-300 small pics, at approx 30-40kB each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a database, i would organize my photos in database with only the path to the photo. And the photos can be stored on memorycard or on local disk.

Comment: No memorycard on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Store all the pics in document folder, and when there is no internet connection get them from document folder of your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of thumb is to put big data objects like images right onto the disk and only reference the URLs. This might come in handy for loading/processing the images anyway.

30-40 kB per image is not that much, but then I'd consider 6-12 MB for the database quite extensive, especially it's probably the majority of your database volume.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real familiar with iOS. But my understanding is that it supports XML files. If the database is just being used to store the paths (instead of images), why not use an xml file to store the paths?

If you need the db, with small images, I don't see it being a problem if the phone is just using it. Either way, I don't think it'll be an issue. Someone else can probably give you a better answer as far as efficiency. That's outside my jurisdiction.